# SyntaxError: missing brackets after argument list

Tags: javascript

Get this JavaScript error, and I don't get well where exactly to add the brackets

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

```
function showContacts(){
    console.log('Showing Contacts...');
    setTimeout("$('#pageContent').load('contacts.php',functions(){$('loaderImage').hide();})",1000);
}
```

Comment: Typo: `functions()` != `function()` - personally I would setTimeout a function with that JS string inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo: `function` should be used instead of `functions`(Notice extra `s` at the end)

```
function showContacts() {
    console.log('Showing Contacts...');
    setTimeout("$('#pageContent').load('contacts.php',function(){$('loaderImage').hide();})", 1000);
}
```

Comment: Also recommend using `anonymous function` instead of `string`

Comment: thank you guyz it has worked